# Rails pass extra parameters to a request without using hidden_field tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I have two models named Post and PostComment.
At present, I use `hidden_field` form helpers to send extra data like post time, user ID of the comment poster and the post ID on which the comment is being made like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :posttime, value: Time.now.getutc %>
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, value: @post.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

It clicked late to me that I can change these values using the browser's inspectors and hence that's a security breach. So how do I send these parameters securely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually these values aren't passed via the form, but are accessed via the URL using nested URLs (read how here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

eg to use the `post_id` form the url, you'd set your comment route to include the post eg you'd have `new_post_comment_path` and in your controller you could access `params[:post_id]` without passing it through the form.

Your form would become something like this:

```
<% form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
   ...
```

re: `user_id` - definitely don't pass that in a form, you're quite right that this is a big security concern (people could add comments for other people!) Just access it via your authentication methods (ie `current_user`) in your controller.

You'd end up with something like this in your controller eg:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to [@post, @comment]
  else
    render_action :new
  end
end

private

# Don't forget to use require/permit to make sure the user can't 
# fake up the user/post id fields themselves out of whole-cloth
def comment_params
  # or whatever your permitted comment-fields are.
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing many things out for me. I didn't know that the `post_id` parameter automatically gets passed, now it makes more sense. Since I'm using devise, shouldn't it be `@post_comment.user_id = current_user.id` (implying that your line of code is wrong or at least not following the convention)

Comment: As long as you have a `belongs_to :user` in the `Comment` model, you can use `user` or `user_id` and they'll both Just Work :)
If you have a validation on one or the other though - use the one with the validation... (eg `validates_presence_of :user_id` means you should prefer `@comment.user_id = current_user.id`)

Comment: Great! Since we are filing in the user ID in the controller itself and I've made sure the form is visible to user only if he's signed in, there is no requirement for the `validates_presence_of :user_id` right?

Comment: It's often a good idea to have the validation just as a backup.  You never know where the future might lead... and keeping your data integrity pure is important (because it's *such* a huge headache later on if you later find dodgy data in your db)

Comment: Being a paranoid can save the day someday :)
Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

The `Time.now.getutc` and `current_user.id` are already available in your application at the `create` and `update` methods so you don't really need to pass those back.  As for `@post.id` you could just store that in a session variable in your `new` or `edit` methods...

```
session[post_id] = @post.id
```

and then in your `create` or `update methods...

```
@post_comment.post_id = session[:post_id]
```

Comment: It totally didn't occur to me that the `Time.now.utc` can be used inside controller itself. Thanks for spotting it out.